# can't delete or load the table mysql "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1021 Disk full"

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i am facing the following problem

1. imported survey.sql [4.gb] file. it was in infinite loop of
   inserting record. loading and loading.
2. when i browse my site, it start showing me mysql error message
3. SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1021 Disk full (/var/tmp/#sql_4a67_3); waiting for someone to free some space...
4. now i can't remove my table or can't load it. just stuck with it.

i want to drop that table but whenever i execute "`drop table survey;`" 
i is just infinite loop. i am using  `sequel pro`

i do also have SSH access.

Update: [image]

Comment: stop the mysql service. then free up some space and restart the database.

Comment: by the was is that bad question. it is down voted ?

Comment: Not me who downvoted

Comment: Don't worry about downvotes. Some people reflexively downvote questions with important parts of them shown as images.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ssh to access the server machine running MySQL.

then ...

```
cd /var/tmp
df -h .
```

This will tell you how much space is available on that filesystem. Not much, I'll wager.

then ...

```
du -sh *
```

will tell you how much space each folder or file in `/var/tmp` is using, and ...

```
ls -lh
```

will tell you the names and owners of the files.

Delete some.  Try your MySQL operations again.

Don't let the filesystem holding that tmp directory fill up in production.

In future, when you have vast `.sql` files to run, try breaking them up into smaller files of about 10,000 INSERTs each.

Comment: If you're not the administrator of the machine running the MySQL server, buy that person a beer or some flowers or something and ask for help.

Comment: he gave me all the access before we let him go :)

Comment: don"t forget to restart server if size didn't change ;-)